# Question marks ("?") in QGIS layer panel when using SVG markers defined with "Data defined override"

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, svg, data-defined-override

When using SVG marker symbols and set the path to SVG file via **Data defined override** the SVGs display well in the map canvas, but not in the layers panel (applies for QGIS 2.x and 3.x).

SVG marker symbol setup:

[image]

Expression for Data defined override (Note the output preview):

```
@svg_path || '\\baustelle_laufend.svg'
```

(This is build from a variable holding different paths to SVG symbols in various environments and the SVG file name itself)

[image]

The correct display in the *Symbol Selector* and in the map canvas as well proves that this approach works fine, but in the layers panel the SVG symbols are replaced by some ugly question marks:

[image]

Why is that so? Is this a bug?

Comment: The path is using slashes while the filename is added using a backslash. Would it work if you set the filename with a slash?

Comment: @JGH just tried replacing '\\' by '/', but unfortunately no effect...

Comment: Is it actual for new versions of QGIS?